# Arduino Ethernet Shield Not Connecting to WebServer

Tags: connection, webserver, client, arduino, ethernet

I have a problem making my Arduino Ethernet shield to communicate with the server, 
the result on the serial monitor is always:

my arduino code is

```
#include <Ethernet.h>           //library for ethernet functions
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Dns.h>
#include <Client.h>             //library for client functions
#include <DallasTemperature.h>  //library for temperature sensors

// Ethernet settings
byte mac[] = {0x09,0xA2,0xDA,0x00,0x01,0x26};  //Replace with your Ethernet shield MAC
byte ip[] = { 192,168,0,54};  //The Arduino device IP address
byte subnet[] = { 255,255,255,0};
byte gateway[] = { 192,168,0,1};
IPAddress server(192,168,0,53);                  // IP-adress of server arduino sends data to

EthernetClient client;

bool connected = false;                                

void setup(void) {                                     

    Serial.begin(9600);                                
    Serial.println("Initializing Ethernet.");
    delay(1000);
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip , gateway , subnet);    

}

void loop(void) {                                      

    if(!connected)   {                                 
      Serial.println("Not connected");
      if (client.connect(server, 80)) {                
          connected = true;
          int temp =analogRead(A1);                    
          Serial.print("Temp is ");                              
          Serial.println(temp);
          Serial.println();
          Serial.println("Sending to Server: ");                 
          client.print("GET /formSubmit.php?t0=");            
          Serial.print("GET /formSubmit.php?t0=");            
          client.print(temp);
          Serial.print(temp);
          client.println(" HTTP/1.1");                  
          Serial.println(" HTTP/1.1");                  
          client.println("Host: http://localhost/PhpProject1/");    
          Serial.println("Host: http://localhost/PhpProject1/");    
          client.println("User-Agent: Arduino");        
          Serial.println("User-Agent: Arduino");        
          client.println("Accept: text/html");          
          Serial.println("Accept: text/html");          
          //client.println("Connection: close");        
          //Serial.println("Connection: close");        
          client.println();                             
          Serial.println();
          delay(10000);                                            
      }
      else{
        Serial.println("Cannot connect to Server");               
      }
    }  
    else {
      delay(1000);                                              
      while (client.connected() && client.available()) {        
        char c = client.read();                                 
        Serial.print(c);                                        
      }                                                         
      Serial.println();                                         
      client.stop();                                            
      connected = false;                                        
    }
}
```

the server is an Apache server running on a pc, the server ip address in the code is the pc ip address. For testing purposes I work at my homes network, there's no proxy or firewall, and I also turned of the antivirus and firewall on my pc.

the result in the serial monitor is always:

```
Not connected
Cannot connect to Server
```

Any thoughts??

Comment: Is the server running? What does `telnet 192.168.0.53 80` return? Are you connecting over a proxy or firewall (doesn't seem so, but have to ask)? Perhaps try the simpler `Ethernet.begin( mac , ip )` to rule out issues with the gateway.

Comment: the server is an Apache server running on  a pc, the server ip address is the pc ip address. the `telnet 192.168.0.53 80` works successfully.
For testing purposes I work at my homes network, there's no proxy or firewall, and I also turned of the antivirus and firewall on my pc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked, the problem was in `Ethernet.begin(mac, ip , gateway , subnet)`, I removed this line and configure the Ethernet Shield using the DHCP, `Ethernet.begin(mac)`

Comment: I am having the same issue but DHCP did no solve my problem. I do get an IP assigned but, but when connecting i get the Not connected
Cannot/connect to Server errors any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified the MAC address is correct?

If it still doesn't work, try using

```
Client client(server, 80);
```

in stead of

```
EthernetClient client
```

And change

```
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
```

to

```
if (client.connect()) {
```

Hope this helps