# Acces to an URL with Arduino Ehernet shield

Tags: arduino

I am trying to access a [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) file in my server with an Arduino and the Ethernet [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields). This file captures the URL parameters "Sensor" and "Value" and stores the read data into a database.

This is my code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

EthernetClient client;

byte MACaddress[] = {0xDE,0xAD,0xBE,0xEF,0xFE,0xED};
byte IPaddress[] = {10,0,0,178};
byte DNSserverIPaddress[] = {4,4,4,4};
byte gatewayIPaddress[] = { 10, 0, 0, 100 };
byte subnetMask[] = { 255, 255, 255, 0 };
char serverName[] = "log.server.com";


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Ethernet.begin(MACaddress, IPaddress, DNSserverIPaddress, gatewayIPaddress, subnetMask);
}


void loop()
{
    delay (5000);

    Serial.println("connecting to server...");
    client.connect(serverName, 80);
    Serial.println("making HTTP request...");
    client.println("GET /logger.php?sensor=temp&value=19 HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("HOST: log.server.com");
    client.println();
}
```

After uploading this code to my [Arduino Mega](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega) + Ethernet shield, nothing changes in my database...

What is wrong?

Comment: Does your arduino connect to the web server at all? Test that by setting up i.e. a python http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html SimpleHTTPServer and then connecting to that using the arduino. Or check the server logs. And check whether your database does behacve correctly when you call the URL from a "normal" browser from your PC. You'll need to find out which part exactly is broken.

Comment: If I acces directly to the url with my navigator, it works.

Comment: Have you read this similar question, where the problem was with DHCP? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122958/arduino-ethernet-shield-not-connecting-to-webserver?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you should add a condition check to know if the Arduino think it worked or not:

```
if (client.connect(...)) { 
    /* Stuff you do on success */
} 
else { 
    Serial.println("failure! :-(") 
}
```

- If it does print `failure!` you got a network configuration problem on the Arduino side. If it does work, the problem is after the Arduino.

Then try opening a server with `nc -kl 42000` and change the port you connect to on `42000` in the Arduino [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch), to be sure whether the network connection works.

- If it does work, then you've got a problem on your host side (the webserver), if it does not, you may have a problem on the network between the Arduino and the host.

You should then try to connect to a server's [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) instead of a [fully qualified domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) (FQDN). If that works, it may be the DNS server that is unreachable, and you should try to use `8.8.8.8` instead (or your local network's DNS server).

Also check that the IP address you're using is indeed free of use (and not assigned by a [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) or used by another computer), as well as the [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) is really unused... (addresses like `{0xDE,0xAD,0xBE,0xEF,0xFE,0xED}` tend to be used a lot in hacks...).

My opinion, is that your bug is the DNS server that is unreachable, as there's no DNS resolver opened on `4.4.4.4`.

Comment: Done! I found a connection problem ,then I have mounted a local server and it works. The problem is relative to the DHCP. Thanks!!!